# fast ways to clip buffered images in java.awt

Tags: java, graphics, awt

i need a way to draw a part of a buffered image. luckily the part of it i need to draw is very simple, i just need to draw a horizontal slice of it- some band of the image from a lower bound to a higher bound. other graphics languages have functions to draw 'clips' of images, or sometimes functions to copy images onto new images with different sizes

i looked into those kinds of clip functions for java.awt but ended up just going with this manual function that just draws right onto the canvas. it looks like this

```
public void clipImage(BufferedImage img,int ixa,int iya,int ixb,int iyb,int cxa,int cya,int cxb,int cyb){
        float wr = ((float)img.getWidth()/(1f+ixb-ixa));
        float hr = ((float)img.getHeight()/(1f+iyb-iya));
        for(int x = Math.max(ixa+1,cxa);x <= Math.min(ixb,cxb);x ++){
            for(int y = Math.max(iya+1,cya);y <= Math.min(iyb,cyb);y ++){
                int px = (int)((x-ixa)* wr);
                int py = (int)((y-iya)* hr);
                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(px,py),true);
                if(c.getAlpha()>0){
                    g2.setColor(c);
                    g2.fillRect(x-1,y-1,1,1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this works, but it's slow. it seems slower to draw a part of an image using this function than to draw the entire image normally, which is bad. is there a better way to do this? thanks

Comment: BufferedImage#subImage? Graphics also has a clip method, although playing with that cause some interesting side effects

Comment: oh that looks like the partial image copy thing i was looking for. that'll probably work thanks

Comment: ok it looks like this is slightly faster- thanks. it still doesn't seem totally optimal relative to the speed of drawing a whole image, i'm thinking the added extra step of drawing to an external buffer and then to the canvas is wasting a lot of time, but this is better than what i was doing before

Comment: Take a look at `Graphics#clip`, although you'd be doing it reverse (clipping the area of the graphics and then placing the image in such away as to only paint the area you want)